# Jquery how to on again after click to off?

Tags: jquery, function, click

https://codepen.io/jh-ko/pen/EJYbWZ

After i clicked "button", the click function has to be stop.
And i want to on it again, after i clicked another function "again".
But the click function of the "button" doesnt work again.

How can i on the click function again?

```
$('.button').click(function() {
  $('.item01').css('transform', 'rotate(323deg)');
  $(".button").off('click');
})

$(".again").click(function(){
  $(".button").on('click');
})
```

Comment: You have to give `on()` the callback again.  Extract the method to a named function that is easily referenced/reused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Reuse the method

```
function doSomething () {
    $('.item01').css('transform', 'rotate(323deg)');
    $(".button").off('click');
}

$('.button').on('click', doSomething);

$(".again").click(function(){
  $(".button").on('click', doSomething);
});
```

## Or use a class

```
function doSomething () {
    if ($(this).is(':not(.ignore)')) {
      $('.item01').css('transform', 'rotate(323deg)');
      $(this).addClass('ignore');
    }
}

$('.button').on('click', doSomething);

$(".again").click(function(){
  $(".button").removeClass('ignore');
});
```

## Or use a class with a delegate event listener

```
function doSomething () {
  $('.item01').css('transform', 'rotate(323deg)');
  $(this).addClass('ignore');
}

$(document).on('click', '.button:not(.ignore)', doSomething);

$(".again").click(function(){
  $(".button").removeClass('ignore');
});
```